# Copying file using binary mode

Tags: binary, copy

I kind of have a possibly stupid question , but I can't find exact information in Google.
It's about copying file using binary mode,no matter extension.
Lets say we have file with extension .x :
1.Open it in our program in binary mode.
2.Copy all the bits in there and paste it into another new one with the same extension.

I know that this will work for a lot of different extensions(like .txt),but is this working for all of them.I mean can we do this for .jpg. Will we get the same image if we do this or we need some kind of compression for some extensions ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Yes - binary mode should treat everything as it is seen and not modify the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing a binary copy, you need to do nothing special.  Only if you're changing the content of e.g. a JPG by changing the compression ratio or scaling the size of the image do you need to try to interpret the content.